# Fine tune Tensorflow Universal sentence encoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I  want to fine tune Tensorflow Universal sentence encoder. But when I try to use own data as input to Keras layer with sentence encoder I got the error

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4" 
model = hub.load(module_url)
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model, output_shape=[512], dtype=tf.string)
hub_layer(np.array('test sentence'))
```

```
InvalidArgumentError:  input must be a vector, got shape: []
```

I tried different variants of input data: strings, numpy arrays, but it didn't work. Does anybody know what this model takes as input and how can I adapt my own data for this?

Comment: Try a list of strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60991253/invalidargumenterror-input-must-be-a-vector-got-shape

Comment: It's not a duplicate. In that question saving the embeddings of text data is needed. And I want vice-a-versa - to add text data inside  Embedding as part of Keras model

Comment: @JayMody thanks! List of strings  worked as input to Embeddings layer. Also I had to delete `output_shape=[512]` from 
`hub.KerasLayer(model, output_shape=[512], dtype=tf.string)`
and it's strange because the output of layer is `TensorShape([strings amount, 512])`